# Update object in relation by Hibernate ORM in Java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, sql-update

I have question about access to data.
I have that DB:

```
[country: id, country_name],
[city: id, country_id, city_name],
[address: id, shop_data_id, city_id, address_data],
[shop_data: id, data]
```

My relations `country-city` one to many, `city-address` one to many, `address-shop_data` one to one.
I'm looking for information that can I do that SQL query with ORM, or what is the best way do do it in ORM.

```
UPDATE shop_data 
INNER JOIN country ON country.id=1
INNER JOIN city ON country.id=city.country_id 
INNER JOIN address ON city.id= address.city_id 
INNER JOIN shop_data ON address.shop_data_id=shop_data.id 
SET shop_data.data="shop data string" 
WHERE shop_data.id=address.shop_data_id
```

I know that in SQL I should start by `shop_data`, but by doing this I want to show that I want start in ORM by `country` entity.

I wrote entities in Hibernate with annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name="country")
public class Country{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // getters/setters ..
}

@Entity
@Table(name="city")
public class City{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Address> adresses = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="country_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Country country;

    // getters/setters ..
}


@Entity
@Table(name="address")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "district")
    private String district;
    @Column(name = "post_code")
    private String postCode;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="shop_data_id")
    private ShopData shopData;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="city_id")
    private City city;
    
    // getters/setters ..

}

@Entity
@Table(name="shop_data")
public class shopData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "data")
    private String data;
    
    // getters/setters ..
}
```

I know that I can use getters starting from `country` that returns `List<ObjectType>` and from there get my object. Next run function `update` and update right row. But in this way are done some number of queries.

Is it possible to do by Java Hiberante ORM by one query? Or which way is the best to minimize query amount? By this method I also want to update next also address data.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely read a book about JPA/Hibernate to understand what JPQL or HQL supports. You can just do joins as you do them with SQL, except for DML statement, but you don't need that. In your case a simple subquery is enough to model what you need. A possible query could look like the following:

```
UPDATE ShopData s
SET s.data="shop data string" 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Country c
  WHERE c.id = 1 AND c.city.address.shopData.id = s.id
)
```